# Does sequences related to function for $lcm(1,2,3 \cdots n)$ exists?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, closed-form

This just came out of curiosity let $$L(n)=lcm(1,2,3 \cdots n)$$ and I know that we can write this with the help of some product involving primes and all . But what I am interested is in

Does $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{L(n)}{(n!)^2}$$ exists ?  If yes than what is it equal to ?And another thing is does $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{L(n)}$$ exists ? If yes is there a close form for it?

Comment: Since $(n-1)n \leqslant L_n \leqslant n!$, both series converge. I don't expect a nice closed form for either.

Comment: This sequence arises in Analytic Number Theory. In a more general form, where we take the lcm of arithmetic progressions, I found a paper that establishes some lower bounds. The references contained talk about this sequence in particular. For instance, Hanson's 1972 paper. Here is the article I found: http://math.stanford.edu/~dankane/lcmbound.pdf

Comment: $L(n)$ is the exponent of the symmetric group $S_n$. See [Landau's Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function).  
Asymptotic estimates are known.

Comment: [OEIS A003418](https://oeis.org/A003418) gives many references to this sequence in the literature, some of which might address your specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$0\leq \Sigma \frac{l(n)}{(n!)^2}\leq\Sigma \frac{n!}{(n!)^2}=\Sigma \frac{1}{n!}=e-1 $$

Comment: Thank you for note, I correct it.